# How can I reindex pandas dataframe to reset the starting index value to zero？

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe, there are NaN values in some rows. I want to delete these rows. I solve it with dataframe.dropna(how='any'). The result looks like:

```
         date  time   open   hign    low  close  volume  turnover
2  2015-09-01   931  48.60  48.60  48.00  48.00  449700  21741726
3  2015-09-01   932  47.91  48.33  47.91  48.25  158500   7614508
```

I want to reindex the rows of my dataframe, so I run:

```
length = dataframe.dropna(how='any').shape[0]
dataframe1 = dataframe.index(range(length))
```

But dataframe1 still keeps the old index values, like：

```
          date  time   open   hign    low  close  volume  turnover
0         NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
1         NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
2  2015-09-01   931  48.60  48.60  48.00  48.00  449700  21741726
3  2015-09-01   932  47.91  48.33  47.91  48.25  158500   7614508
```

How can I make the number begin with 0 and delete the first two rows?

Desired result:

```
          date  time   open   hign    low  close  volume  turnover
0  2015-09-01   931  48.60  48.60  48.00  48.00  449700  21741726
1  2015-09-01   932  47.91  48.33  47.91  48.25  158500   7614508
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reset the index and specify `drop=True`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': [nan, nan, 48.0, 48.25],
                   'date': [nan, nan, '2015-09-01', '2015-09-01'],
                   'hign': [nan, nan, 48.60, 48.33],
                   'low': [nan, nan, 48.0, 47.91],
                   'open': [nan, nan, 48.60, 47.91],
                   'time': [nan, nan, 931.0, 932.0],
                   'turnover': [nan, nan, 21741726.0, 7614508.0],
                   'volume': [nan, nan, 449700.0, 158500.0]})

>>> df
         date  time   open   hign    low  close  volume  turnover
0         NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
1         NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN
2  2015-09-01   931  48.60  48.60  48.00  48.00  449700  21741726
3  2015-09-01   932  47.91  48.33  47.91  48.25  158500   7614508

>>> df.dropna(how='any').reset_index(drop=True)
         date  time   open   hign    low  close  volume  turnover
0  2015-09-01   931  48.60  48.60  48.00  48.00  449700  21741726
1  2015-09-01   932  47.91  48.33  47.91  48.25  158500   7614508
```

Comment: Thanks.That helps me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) functionality?